# Redirect specific page with query using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

for example

> **mydomain.com**/jobresultpage?what=&where=Arkansas

redirect to

> **yourdomain.com**/jobresultpage?what=&where=Arkansas

but other page like

> mydomain.com/about.html
>
> mydomain.com/contact.html

not redirect..

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the rules below to the .htaccess file located in the root directory of `mydomain.com`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mydomain\.com$ [NC]
#redirect any request for jobresult to yourdomain
RewriteRule ^jobresultpage$ http://yourdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Make sure you have mod_rewrite installed, and your Override properties set to read the .htaccess files.